# How to use custom map provider (tiles, dimensions) on GmapControl, Gmap.NET?

Tags: c#, google-maps

I want to create a custom map with dimensions and tiles with Gmap.NET in C#, there's limited information generally about the framework. An example of something useful would be greatly appreciated!

```
    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainMap.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
        MainMap.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        MainMap.MinZoom = 2;
        MainMap.MaxZoom = 17;

        MainMap.Zoom = 2;
    }
```

This is how I'm initializing it right now.

Comment: Have you tried this tutorials? It might help you: (http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/) and (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32643/GMap-NET-Great-Maps-for-Windows-Forms-and-Presenta)

Answer (score 0):

```
 map = new GMapControl();
                map.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
                GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;                   
                map.Position = new PointLatLng(141.7432194, 20.9836962);
                map.MaxZoom = 50;
                map.MinZoom = 2;
                map.Zoom = 11;
```